# Javascript for loop not adding up correctly

Tags: javascript, regex

I get size of the PDF files within the name of the the file on page

```
console.log($(opt).text() + " selected")
```

`opt` has the value such as `abcs{853269}`

I get the value using regular expression:

```
var curSize = $(opt).text();
console.log(curSize + "current Size");

var counter = 0;
var result = curSize.match(/{(.*?)}/);
console.log('sizee' + result);
```

The console result is `{853269},853269`

I don't know why I am getting two results, I thought regex will only return one.

Now I have a for loop to calculate all the values that are selected and give it back to me as one big sum:

```
if ( result !=null){
    for(var i=0; i< result.length; i++){
        counter += result[i];
        document.getElementById("textarea").value += result[i];
    }
    console.log(counter + "Counter");
}
```

...but it's crashing.

Comment: `result[0]` is the whole match, and the rest of the elements are the contents of the capturing groups. `result[1]` is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the [regex documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) you can see it returns:

> An Array containing the entire match result and any
>   parentheses-captured matched results, or null if there were no
>   matches.

Your first item in the array is the entire expression that was matched by the regex. The second item that you see is the value extracted from the match group (your parenthesis). Use the second value directly.

```
var result = curSize.match(/{(.*?)}/);

var extractedText = undefined;
if(result) {
    extractedText = result[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what MDN says about `String.prototype.match` ([page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)):

> The match() method retrieves the matches when matching a string against a regular expression.

With your current regular expression, there's an item (in the array returned from `String.match`) for a match to the entire regular expression. That explains the first result (`{853269}`).

The second item in the resulting array (`853269`), is coming from the [group](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#grouping-back-references) that you defined in your regular expression.